# Extract full list of rss feed using simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm using a code to extract the items from an ebay rss feed, the only problem is that it is only extracting one item.

I suspected it was because of `for each`, but after searching this whole site, I couldn't find a solution. The feed URL will output 8 items (entriesPerPage=8), if you access the feed, you'll that the full xml code is there, but the parser is only getting one item.

```
<?php

$feedurl = "http://rest.ebay.com/epn/v1/find/item.rss?keyword=%28jewelry%2Ccraft%2Cclothing%2Cshoes%2Cdiy%29&sortOrder=BestMatch&programid=1&campaignid=5337945426&toolid=10039&listingType1=All&lgeo=1&topRatedSeller=true&hideDuplicateItems=true&entriesPerPage=8&feedType=rss";

$rss = simplexml_load_file($feedurl);

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {

$link = $item->link;

$title = $item->title;

$description = $item->description;

}

?>
<div class="mainproductebayfloatright-bottom">
<div class="aroundebay">
<?
print "<div class=\"titleebay\">" . $title . "</div>";
print $description;
?>
</div>
</div>

?>
```

Comment: Probably because you're looping through one item?  $rss->channel->item

Comment: but since it's `foreach`, shouldn't it get each item on page, instead of just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your html inside a loop, as currently on each iteration your variables are **overwritten** and after the loop is over what you have is values of the last xml-item:

```
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    $link = $item->link;
    $title = $item->title;
    $description = $item->description;?>
    <div class="mainproductebayfloatright-bottom">
        <div class="aroundebay">
    <?php
        // simple title
        print "<div class=\"titleebay\">" . $title . "</div>";
        // title-link
        print "<a href=\"" . $link . "\">" . $title . "</div>";
        print $description;
    ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Your code is returning a blank page, I even activate the error reporting, but it shows no errors at all. Also, why there is an open php tag with a parenthesis in the end? Thx in advance

Comment: Use `<?php` instead of `<?`.  `open php tag with a parenthesis in the end` closes a foreach loop.

Comment: Still not working. What version of php are you running?

Comment: Checked returned xml, there's really `->item` field. So return `->item` back. Edited my answer.

Comment: Dang, it solved the problem. I owe you a beer now! :D

Comment: One last question, is it possible to transform the title into a link?